# CodeIgniter - How to return Json response from controller

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

How do I return response from the controller back to the Jquery Javascript?

Javascript

```
$('.signinform').submit(function() { 
   $(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
       type : "POST",
       url: 'index.php/user/signin', // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
       cache : false,
       success : onSuccessRegistered,
       error: onFailRegistered
   });        
   return false; 
});
```

Data is returned null (blank)!

```
function onSuccessRegistered(data){
    alert(data);
};
```

Controller -

```
public function signin() {
    $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);    
    echo json_encode( $arr );
}
```

Comment: verify have you call the particular method.. The call is reached signin method

Comment: Yes, the call has reached sign in

Comment: success : function(response){ console.log(response)} modify this line and add the header //add the header here
    header('Content-Type: application/json')

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
//do the edit in your javascript

$('.signinform').submit(function() { 
   $(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
       type : "POST",
       //set the data type
       dataType:'json',
       url: 'index.php/user/signin', // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
       cache : false,
       //check this in Firefox browser
       success : function(response){ console.log(response); alert(response)},
       error: onFailRegistered
   });        
   return false; 
}); 


//controller function

public function signin() {
    $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);    

   //add the header here
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode( $arr );
}
```

Comment: Returned (an empty string)

Comment: Shown: {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

Comment: that's correct then you have to add full URL in that ajax url: 'http://<domain>/index.php/user/signin' then check it

Comment: I added ../index.php/user/signin

Comment: But it is not working still. Since Domain name will change, I cannot put a static domain name there.

Comment: Submit is an function so it's trying to send the form details into your form action URL. I think your action URL is empty so it's does the self post instead of ajax submit.
Add the Action URL in from tag and you can try 
http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Hi Sundar, I am using code igniter. I am not able to parse the json_encode.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php try here above 5.2 version this is inbuild functionalty otherwise you have to install it

Comment: It worked . But it overrited some features such as cache in Output class. So Cliff Richard Anfone's answer is better.

Comment: `set_status_header` is not always to be 500. My response return the status code as 200 is for success. Cliff Richard Anfone explains about how to return internal server error response.

Answer (score 95):

```php
return $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_status_header(500)
    ->set_output(json_encode([
        'text' => 'Error 500',
        'type' => 'danger'
    ]));
```

Comment: Why is the "type" value "danger"?

Comment: @VictorS that is your response data, basicly anything you want

Comment: Working great with `'type' => 'danger'` thank you for that tip!

Comment: Please, for Codeigniter 4 use something like: ```return $this->response->setJSON( array(
                    'text' => 'Error 500',
                    'type' => 'danger'
            ) );```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction but I found this as helper for me `return $this->response->setStatusCode(500)->setJSON(['text' => 'Error 500', 'type' => 'danger'] );` when using CI4

Answer (score 6):

For `CodeIgniter 4`, you can use the built-in [API Response Trait](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/api_responses.html)

Here's sample code for reference:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    use ResponseTrait;

    public function index()
    {
        $data = [
            'data' => 'value1',
            'data2' => 'value2',
        ];

        return $this->respond($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

in my case , I'm using ci4 , I send response to clinet like this:
e.g in App\Controllers\Category:setOrder
my Category controller extends **BaseController**

```
  return $this->response->setJson(['msg'=>'update-success']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not your answer and this is an alternate way to process the form submission

```
$('.signinform').click(function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'index.php/user/signin', // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
      dataType:'json',
      success : function(response){ console.log(response); alert(response)}
     });
});
```

Comment: This secondary (non-resolving) advice should have been a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter 4.3, I've used this within a before Filter, that doesn't have a `$this->response` as Controllers do:

```php
return response()->setContentType('application/json')                             
                 ->setStatusCode(401)
                 ->setJSON(['error' => 'Access Denied']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a 4.3.x version solution it is this:

```
return $this->response->setJSON($data);
```

Source: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/response.html#setting-the-output