# make Data not disappear from textbox using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-form-helper

text box value disappear when i clicked the submit button in CI i want to make it not disappear

```
 $textbox_data = array(
     'name'      => 'playlist_text',
     'id'        => 'playlist',
     'maxlength' => '200',
     'size'      => '100',
     'style'     => 'width:1070px',
     'class'     =>  'form-control',
     'value'     => $textbox_value,
);
```

echo form_input($textbox_data);

$textbox_value = $this->input->post('playlist_text',TRUE);

could anyone help me?
thanks :)

Comment: can you elaborate more? when submitting the form refresh but you want to keep the text for each text inputs?

Comment: use ajax post after successfull submit redirect through javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821492/code-igniter-how-to-return-json-response-from-controller/18821655#18821655

Comment: Where you are trying to get $textbox_value post data ?? I think you will get your post data in your controller file.

Comment: 'value' => set_value('playlist_text', $textbox_value)

Answer (score 1):

You can use set_value() function:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('category_title');?>" placeholder="Category Title" id="category_title" class="form-control" name="category_title">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: [CodeIgniter's Form Helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

> set_value()
>
> Permits you to set the value of an input form or textarea. You must
>   supply the field name via the first parameter of the function. The
>   second (optional) parameter allows you to set a default value for the
>   form. Example:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo set_value('quantity', '0');?>" size="50" />
```

> The above form will show "0" when loaded for the first time.