# Codeigniter: Using button click to view more data from database

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Ideally, In my database table, I have username, name, location, email.

Now I have a table in my **view.php** where it returns value from the database.

*Table* header consists of name, username, and more info where ***name*** and ***username*** comes directly from the database while ***more info*** will have a button for each row. When the button is clicked, it should display location and email in a pop up.

> Question: How can I retrieve location and email of a user when the button is clicked specifically?

Example:

user1, joe doe, [button] -> user1 location, user1@email.com

user2, jay doe, [button] -> user2 location, user2@email.com

Codes: *p.s. code includes pagination.*

**controller.php**

```
function pagination() {
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . "controller/pagination";
        $total_row = $this->model->record_count();
        $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
        $config["per_page"] = 8;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        /* $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE; */
        $config['num_links'] = $total_row;
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
        $config['next_link'] = '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '<span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;


        $data["results"] = $this->model->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);
        $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);

        // View data according to array.
        $this->load->view("view-employees", $data);
    }
```

**model.php**

```
public function record_count() {
    return $this->db->count_all('users');
}

public function fetch_data($limit, $start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**view.php**

```
<tr>
    <th>username</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>more</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <?php foreach ($results as $data) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $data->username; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data->name; ?></td>
    <td>
        <button type='button' class='btn'>
           <?php echo $data->location; 
                 echo $data->email;
           ?>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: adding some code would be nice ..

Comment: @AbdullaNilam added.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could write a Codeigniter-controller which will return email and location
2. Then you write Javascript-functions which will call this controller to retrieve the data asJSON-Data

Both, writing a controller which returns JSON and an example how to call this controller from JS can be found here:

[Code Igniter - How to return Json response from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821492/code-igniter-how-to-return-json-response-from-controller)

Comment: I have updated my post together with the codes. Can you check please?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

MODEL:

```
public function record_count() {
    return $this->db->count_all('users');
}

public function fetch_data($limit, $start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
         return $query->result_array();
        }


    }
    return false;
}
```

View:

```
<tr>
    <th>username</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>more</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <?php foreach ($results as $data) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $data['username']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['name']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <button type='button' class='btn'>
           <?php echo $data['location']; 
                 echo $data['email'];
           ?>
        </button>
    </td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Yes, it does work perfectly if echo it out directly to the button. Is there a possible way to echo it in a pop up?

Comment: yes you can study about bootstrap model.set some html with attribute..I hope you can do it.

Comment: see here about model http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: if you got help form this answer feel free to accept ans vote up.best of luck ahead.