# DataTables - Server-side dumping JSON data when echo json_encode

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to apply server-side DataTables with Codeigniter, my controller code is:

```
 function get_logins() {

    $get_logins = $this->login_attempts_model->get_datatble();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($get_logins as $row){
        $subarray= array();
        $subarray[] = $row->id;
        $subarray[] = $row->ip_address;
        $subarray[] = $row->login_username;
        $subarray[] = $row->time;
        $subarray[] = $row->status;
        $subarray[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row->id.'"class="btn btn-danger">delete</button>';
        $data[]=$subarray;
    }
    $output = array(
        "draw" => $this->input->post(['draw']),
        "recordsTotal" => $this->login_attempts_model->get_all_data(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $this->login_attempts_model->count_filtered_data(),
        "data" => $data
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

and my view code including Jquery is:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#login_data').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order": [],
        "ajax": {
            url: "<?= site_url('login_attempts/get_logins'); ?>",
            type: "POST",
            },
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [4],
                "orderable": false,
            },
        ],
    });// also there are rest of other functions 
    </script>
```

```html
<table id="login_data" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered results">
    <thead>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>IP Address</th>
    <th>Username </th>
    <th>Login Time</th>
    <th>actiona</th>
<th>Login Status</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Everything goes fine and data fill up the table, but `echo json_encode($output)`
is dumping data on the same page as JSON formatted data not only captured by the AJAX method.

[image: the out put]

Comment: If your php code and html code is in same file, then it will show you two output, one in the browser itself and other one you are rendering using ajax. Please place the php code in a separate file and make a call to that external file.

Comment: it's not working, I tried to do that.. still the same issue..

Comment: Try this solution to send json data
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762310/4816207

Comment: sorry again!! it's not working, it redirected me to HTML view  @PrashantPokhriyal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dealing with this issue the solution was very simple:
don't call method  `get_logins()` from php controller
add ajax method when document on load:

```js
$(document).load(function () {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'login_attempts/get_logins',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
});
```

this will resolve the problem of calling the method from controller and again from inside `.dataTbles()` method on ajax (it seems ambiguous but this is the only explanation I've figure it out)