fail in json response in codeigniter 3 controller method
in my codeigniter view page i have a form submission process;
which in controller method i use following for this process:
$FORM_KURALLARI = PROFIL_OLUSTURMA_FORM_KURALLARI();
$this->form_validation->set_rules($FORM_KURALLARI);
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    log_message('debug','unvalid form=='.json_encode(validation_errors()));;
    $response = array(
        'durum' => "warning",
        'icon' => 'fa-times',
        'mesaj' => validation_errors(),
        'buton1' => ceviri('Tamam', true)
    );
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($response));
    return;
}  

here while the errors could be logged successfully, json response does not displayed at all;
what cause this problem? and how could i resolve that?

Have you tried return $this->oputput->set...;? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821492/how-to-return-json-response-from-controller

yes. i try but its also not working.
